# Как посадить свой домен на свой сайт, который на домашнем компе?

Tags: сервер, хостинг, домен

У меня статический ip. Текущие настройки - на картинке видно, что сейчас в настройках, в качестве записи A указал свой статический ip, больше в 1-ой табличке ничего не трогал, далее в табличке с ns-server'ами установил сервера хостинга 500mb.net, хотел туда свой сайт переместить, но там послали меня на F.A.Q., в общем гиблое дело, ничего там не пойму, думаю лучше уже тогда пусть сайт у меня на компе будет, хоть это и не безопасно, но хотя бы для того чтобы знать как это делается такой вариант волне мне по душе.Так вот заморочка с этими DNS, я так понимаю теперь вместо тех ns1.500mb.net и ns2.500mb.net нужно прописать теперь свои DNS, которые выдал мне провайдер, так ли?И если еще что-нть нужно для приручения домена, пожалуйста объясните.p.s. то что на компе сайт должен быть на одной из сборок сервера это мы знаем.![alt text][1]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUOGy.png

Comment: если че вопрос актуален, да и вообще лучше чтобы это кто-нть в качестве отдельной статьи оформил на своем блоге, а еще лучше с видео. Конечно, если такое уже есть то линк плз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему не дать в адрес сайта сразу IP-шник? И не заморачиваццо с DNS/NS/F.A.Q.?:) Конечно, "Мой сайт http://www.moj_sajt.ru" звучит круче, чем "Мой сайт http://127.0.0.1:111"...  Но на мой взгляд - не критично))По поводу остального... Если стоит роутер - проброс порта (если порт не стандартный какой) или в DMZ. Если еще и файрвол - то еще и на нем разрешения на обмен трафиком.

Comment: вот и я об этом. ( о том что круче звучит )

Comment: ИМХО - не критично;)

Comment: зато приятно. А с роутерами и перебросами порта туговато, у меня вообще инет через локалку идет, так что...

Comment: Сайт уже работал, или еще нет?

Comment: И кстати "текущие настройки" откуда взяты?

Comment: сайт не заработал, домен зерегестрирован.

Comment: только что проверил, весьма неожиданный результат, раньше открывало страницу хостинга, а сейчас вообще Соединение было сброшеноВо время загрузки страницы соединение с сервером было сброшено. Мне кажется что-то получилось, надо только сайт у себя на компе настроить.

Comment: у меня сейчас своя сборка apache+mysql+php, может в conf'иге апача вместо того что там сейчас прописать чистый ip, или опять же таки mysite.org.ua, чтобы совпало?

Comment: Если домен зарегистрирован - сменить в записи IP с того, на который зарегистрирован, на твой. Тока все равно - надо проброс будет делать... Придет запрос, а на этом IPсидят еще десяток машин... и куда бедняге деваццо?

Comment: Завтра еще приду, ща бежать надо....)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала меняй только записи типа А в них прописываешь ИП-адрес веб-сервера, сохраняешь ждешь..Если все правильно прописали надо подождать обновления данных ДНС серверов так как после регистрации это занимает от 15минут до 24 часов.Но если локально сайт и регистратор имен рядом(в одном городе или регионе) то это занимает до 1 часа максимум.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю это настройки домена. Зачем вам прописывать в ns записях свой сайт. У вас на компе есть днс сервер? Для вашей задачи достаточно прописать ip в А записи.

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно зарегистрировать внятное доменное имя.

   - [регистрация и продолжение доменных имен](http://ukrhosting.ua/faq.php?id=28)
   - [доменное имя UA](http://www.besthosting.ua/ua/domainua.php)
2. Определиться с хостинг-провайдером. Это может быть тот же регистратор домена.При регистрации домена указываете NS-сервера, которые предлагает ваш хостинг-провайдер. Если вы решили использовать NS-сервера регистратора, укажите в настройках IP-address вашего сайта.
3. Знает ли мир о твоем домене можеш узнать здесь:

   - [What's My DNS](http://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/mysite.org.ua)